# append dates to table and overwrite it once data is available BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, replace, google-bigquery, insert

I have a `my_table` in BigQuery that is being populated on the first of each month. The data looks like this:

```
date          rate    
01/01/22      1.5
01/02/22      1.4
...
01/31/22      1.7
```

On March 1st, 2022 I will have February data (day by day). But while the data for February is not available I need to append rows every day with current_date and null for `rate` column and then overwrite it once the data is available on March 1st.
Desired output is:

```
date          rate    
01/01/22      1.5
01/02/22      1.4
...
01/31/22      1.7
02/01/22      null
02/02/22      null
...
02/17/22      null
```

Comment: Why does your expected output only include the first two days of February and is this what you intended to show us?

Comment: I just added today's date as well. I need to append a row with current date every day until I have data available and then those days that had null values in `rate` column would be overwritten with the values from the update.

Comment: Do you receive those monthly values (on the 1st of each month) in a file or in some other table?

Comment: Its an upload of a file each month, and I was thinking to create another table where I would grab data from original one, do the append and once data is available in the original table, the logic would overwrite what I had for month. Some clause needs to be added that will be checking the date in original table was my guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following logic to automate your process:

1. On the first of every month, check for the arrival of a new file. If its there, add its content to a separate table (call it `monthly_table`).
2. On a daily basis, run a query which combines the output from `monthly_table` and `my_table` and overwrites `my_table` with the merged output.

For (#1), you can run a command which loads data from your file (assuming its a CSV) into `monthly_table`. This can be done with `bq` command line utility, with `--noreplace` flag to ensure that the new data is always appended:

```sh
bq load \
    --source_format=CSV \
    --skip_leading_rows=2 \
    --noreplace \
    mydataset.monthly_table \
    gs://mybucket/data_for_2022_02_01.csv \
    '[{"name": "date", "type": "STRING"}, {"name": "rate", "type": "FLOAT64"}]'
```

For (#2), you can run a query on daily basis which merges both tables, and then overwrite the `my_table` with the output:

```sql
select date, max(rate) as rate from (
   select date, rate from mydataset.monthly_table
      union all
   select date, rate from mydataset.my_table
      union all
   select format_date('%m/%d/%Y', current_date()) as date, null as rate 
)
group by date
order by date
```

You can also use `bq` utility to run the second query (with `--replace=true`) flag.

Comment: Thank you very much @khan! This does exactly what I needed. 